# Search Files with Regular Expressions

Tags: search, regex

Is there a good free tool out there to search files for matches to a regular expression?

I would like to search all files of a specific extension for matches to this expression: `^ := '([a-z0-9]{3})'$`

I would also like it to return (or even better jump to) the line(s) that match.

Anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 3):

[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) will do it.

Comment: Free version does not have multi-line regex search. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to do something like this:

```
find / -name *EXTENSION -exec grep "^ := '([a-z0-9]{3})'$" {} \;
```

It searches the whole drive (`/`) for any files ending in `EXTENSION` and then runs `grep` with your pattern on that file. You can insert any `grep` flags in there to get more specific behavior, but by default it prints out the file name with its matching line.

As Dan suggests, you can further combine this with `sed` to actually manipulate the matching files.

Comment: This will work out of the box if vaccano is running linux.  If not, these commands can be run using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Also look in to [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), great little program for going just this.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest search tool you will ever see is [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) It does not make index, instead it directly access the NTFS records and find your file without even looking and iterating through your hard drive

It supports regular expression

It is my everytime search tool, it shows the result while you are typing, what can be more faster than that?

Comment: Interesting, but I don't know that my hard disk is big enough to "Download Everything for Windows 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 2008 and Windows 7" ;-)

Comment: Looking at the FAQ though - item 1.3 "No, "Everything" does not search file contents, only file and folder names.", which I think means this doesn't answer the question - though the wording of the question isn't clear.

Comment: Its name often confuses while i tell others about it :P , Yup, i am a poor reader and didn't read the last 2 lines of the question with mind. Anyway it will help a lot in your daily file search tasks

Comment: Everything DOES make an index just not a very big one.

Comment: Yes it does make an index, but takes a very little time to do that.

Comment: Everything is THE solution for the question, since version 1.5 (in alpha) it searches for tags, metadata  and content of files, it indexes very fast, even on very large disks with millions of files and on slower PC's, it doesn't "jump" to the contents line though and the regex is for searching files, not IN files. Finding the files is a matter of seconds

Answer (score -1):

`sed`("stream editor") will do it. They have [Sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) as well as for linux (it should be in your package manager if it isn't already in the default install.

Comment: `sed` seems an inappropriate answer - it doesn't just find, it modifies. The classic Unix program for regex search is `grep`, and there are certainly Windows versions around. There will certainly be a version in `MSYS` - but that's kind of a heavyweight solution if all you want is `grep`.

Comment: @Steve314: Perhaps it is an overly complex solution... but it works perfectly fine.  Sed can for the most part encompasses all of greps functionality and a whole lot more, for example a basic grep done in sed is: 's/pattern/&/p'`.  Nerdling's answer of course is much better because it includes the find statement and everything.

Comment: I should have read up on sed again before commenting anyway. Based on vague memories, I thought it edited files in-place. Since it actually edits streams (I should have known really - it's in the name) its a much more sensible answer than I thought.